# sqlite3 in bash script breaks on INSERT

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have a bash scripts that builds a series of INSERT INTOs into a table that has a UNIQUE field as data in the field needs to be unique and could be attempted to be added at a later run.  In my scripts I call

```
/usr/bin/sqlite3 database.db ".read INSERT.sql"
```

I get many:

```
Error: near line 2426: UNIQUE constraint failed: database.fieldname
```

The script works if there are no errors.  How can I prevent sqlite3 from breaking out of the script?

Comment: Remove the unique constraint?

Comment: The script appears to be doing what it is supposed to; perhaps you need to clean up the data you are trying to insert.

Comment: Do you want to skip the duplicates instead of just not having them in your data to start? `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ...`

Comment: Thanks.  INSERT OR IGNORE works perfectly.